# Angularjs - $q.all multiples resource issue

Tags: angularjs

Could you help me solve this issue? How to iterate over the result's elements? angular.forEach(results.first, function(value, key) { //anything } doesn't work too.

```
var AppControllers = angular.module('AppControllers', ['AppConfig']);

AppControllers.controller('WorkItemController', ['$scope', '$q', 'IStatus', 'SRStatus',
   function($scope, $q, IStatus, SRStatus) {

   $q.all({
     first: IStatus.get(),
     second: SRStatus.get()
   }).then(function(results) {

   console.log(results);
   //return Object { first=[0], second=[0]}

   console.log(results.first);
   //return
   //[]
   //0 Resource { Displayable=true, Changeable=true, Open=true, mais...}
   //1 Resource { Displayable=true, Changeable=true, Open=true, mais...}
   //2 Resource { Displayable=false, Changeable=false, Open=false, mais...}
   //3 Resource { Displayable=true, Changeable=false, Open=true, mais...}
   //$promise Object { $$state={...}, then=function(), catch=function(), mais...}
   //$resolved true

   console.log(results.first.length);
   //return 0

   console.log(results.first[1]);
   //return undefined

  });
}]);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$q.all()` works on promises. It looks like `IStatus` is a `$resource`, this means you'll need to use `get().$promise` for `$q.all()` to work properly. Currently, it looks like `$q.all()` is resolving instantly, so when you check the value of the resource, it's still empty.

```
$q.all({
    first: IStatus.get().$promise,
    second: SRStatus.get().$promise
}).then(function(results) {
    // ...
    console.log(results.first); // should contain data
});
```